# unable to read from the second row of csv file in jmeter

Tags: csv, jmeter

using jmeter I am trying to insert the data from csv file using csv data config but it is reading only first row and unable to read from the second row. please help

Comment: please add screenshot of the Test Plan highlighting the CSV Dataset Config. Also, add the CSV file content screenshot.

Comment: i thins it's due to the file format of the CSV file.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/55585434/10789520

Answer (score 1):

If you are using CSV Data Set Config - you need to add **iterations** either at [Thread Group](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Thread_Group) level

[image: Thread Group - number of loops]

or using Loop Controller. See [Using CSV DATA SET CONFIG](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/206733689-Using-CSV-DATA-SET-CONFIG) guide for comprehensive information on JMeter tests parameterisation using CSV files.

An alternative solution is [__CSVRead()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__CSVRead) function which returns a value from CSV file each time it's being called.